# How is this C expression evaluated

Tags: c

Expression is:

```
foo = *p++
```

I am looking for a guide/reference with examples that can explain these things.

I understand postfix `++` has higher precedence than indirection `*`, so the expression is parsed as

```
*(p++)
```

But I am trying to get more clarity on the statement in [GNU C reference manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html#Operator-Precedence) Pg 40, that says:

*Here p is incremented as a side effect of the expression, but foo takes the value of *(p++) rather than (*p)++, since the unary operators bind right to left.*

Comment: That says what you say you already understand, as far as I can tell. It's not clear what sort of clarification you are looking for, can you elaborate?

Comment: @hvd The statement that I quoted was misleading for me. But looks like you have a different opinion on that. I am looking to hear from you further.

Comment: Having read Oli Charlesworth's answer, I do think I understand your question a bit better now. It wasn't clear to me that your question was about the reason *why* `*p++` means `*(p++)`, I read it as asking only for clarification on *whether* `*p++` means `*(p++)`. By now, I have nothing to add that isn't already part of the answers. :)

Comment: @abc: You cited a paragraph referred to "side effects". This could be the source of some kind of confussion. Please, take a look to my answer and tell me if it is the kind of answer you need.

Comment: @pablo1977 Thanks for your answer is. Please see my comments below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP asked "how is evaluated" the expression `*p++`.

One thing is precedence and another different thing is evaluation.
The expression `p++` increments the value of the variable `p`, but the value of the expression is he "old" value that `p` had.

For example, consider that `p` is char pointer used to analyze a string:

```
   char s[] = "0123456789!";
   char *p = s;
   char q;
   p = s;  //  Here *p == '0'
   q = *p++ // Here q == '0' but *p == '1'
```

Although the precedence rules imply that `*p++` is the same that `*(p++)`, the value of `*p++` is `s[0]`, in despite of `p == &s[1]`.
To be more precise, the value of the expression is the same as of `*p`.

In this case, the "side effects" are referring to the operations that are done over the objects, in this case we have the objects `p` and `q` in the expression `q = *p++`.

"Operation over objects" are not walking in the same path that "evaluation of expressions".

Comment: It's true that "evaluation" is a distinct concept, but it's also clear from the OP's post that he/she is really talking about "parsing".

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: (S)He cited a paragraph that talks about "side effects".

Comment: @pablo1977 I was under the assumption that q will have s[1]. I wrote a program confirming that its not. Why doesn't q get the value of expression as it is parsed and evaluated ? And is there a general rule to understand such things ?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I was under (incorrect) assumption that "evaluation" result in this case will be determined by parsing result. But (to my surprise) it is not the case? How to understand these things? Is there a general rule ?

Comment: @abc: Otherwise, there would be no difference between prefix and postfix `++`.

Comment: @abc: As another example, consider `f() + g()`.  There's no guarantee about which function will be called first.

Comment: @abc: That's right: It is not always the case. There are several actions involved in the evaluation of an expression. They are called "side effects". The incremental operators do two different operations: (1) modifies the object p, (2) returns a certain value. These two actions are independent. Another example of side effect could be to raise a floating point exception.

Answer (score 4):

The GNU quote is misleading (IMHO); from a language point-of-view it's nothing to do with left-to-right (or vice versa).<sup>*</sup>

The C language standard doesn't define things in terms of precedence or associativity (left-to-right or right-to-left); these are merely implied by the defined grammar.  Postfix `++` is classified as a *postfix-expression* rather than a *unary-expression*:

> ```
> postfix-expression:
>     primary-expression
>     [...]
>     postfix-expression ++
>     postfix-expression --
>     [...]
>
> unary-expression:
>     postfix-expression
>     ++ unary-expression
>     -- unary-expression
>     unary-operator cast-expression
>     [...]
>
> unary-operator:
>     & * + - ~ !
> ```

The interaction of the above production rules mean that your example is interpreted as `*(p++)`.

In non-standardese, though, the reason is due to precedence, not associativity (which makes little sense for unary operators).

---

<sub>* In fact, the postfix operators are effectively left-to-right, which is the opposite of what's claimed.</sub>

Comment: I disagree here SIR.Why left to right precedence doesn't matter here?

Comment: The GNU quote isn't misleading, it simply isn't using standardese. It's using "unary operator" in its ordinary English meaning, where it means "operator with a single operand".

Comment: @hvd: Perhaps.  But the stuff about "right to left" is simply not the reason.

Comment: Because ++(post-increment) outweighs * operator over here,as you can see through the question.I might be wrong,but,please clarify as to what's my mistake,SIR.

Comment: @shekharsuman: Please re-read my answer, where I explain that the C standard doesn't talk in terms of precedence ("outweighing") or direction.

Comment: Oh,SORRY in this context doesn't matter.I understood,actually it'll matter at other places!

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Again a matter of not using standardese, IMO. If GNU's implementation of the C language is modeled on right-to-left parsing of operators, there's nothing wrong with their documentation referring to such right-to-left parsing. Especially if it gives the exact same results as what the standard requires.

Comment: I don't think there is an unary prefix operator that binds tighter than another unary postfix operator, so it seems legit to say that unary operators bind "right to left".

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Sure, but that's more due to the way the production rules are defined than any explicit notion of associativity.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Are you saying that the Standard doesn't say that `*p++` means `*(p++)` ?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Of course not!  I'm saying that "right to left" is a coincidence of the way the grammar is defined, not something that's explicit.  Postfix operators have higher precedence, and are necessarily on the right; thus *by coincidence*, it's as if the whole thing is evaluated right-to-left.

Answer (score 4):

In C/C++, precedence of Prefix ++ (or Prefix –) and dereference (*) operators is same, and precedence of Postfix ++ (or Postfix –) is higher than both Prefix ++ and *.

If p is a pointer then *p++ is equivalent to *(p++)  (because postfix has higher precedence)

++*p is equivalent to ++(*p) (both Prefix ++ and * are right associative).

*++p is equivalent to *(++p) (both Prefix ++ and * are right associative).

You can see the below 2 programs to clarify your doubt.

Program 1

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
      char arr[] = "overflow";
      char *p = arr;
      ++*p;
      printf(" %c", *p);
      getchar();
      return 0;
 }
Output: p
```

Program 2

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  char arr[] = "overflow";
  char *p = arr;
  *p++;
  printf(" %c", *p);
  getchar();
  return 0;
}
Output: v
```

Comment: Your answer is good but Oli actually answered my question. I did not down vote your answer.

Comment: I think that my answer was more appropriate. But as you may feel :)

Comment: How to do you explain the behavior in pablo's answer? Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 1):

Saying that postfix and unary operators are right-associative (*bind right to left*) is just another way to express the fact that postfix operators have higher precedence in C than unary operators.

Comment: Is it?  Precedence and associativity are largely orthogonal, right?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth For binary operators, sure, it's a bit more complicated than this answer suggests, but for unary operators (and this question is about two unary operators), the effect is exactly the same.

Comment: @hvd: But the postfix operators themselves are effectively *left-to-right*; `p++[5]` means `(p++)[5]`.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Please educate me on how "Precedence and associativity are largely orthogonal". This is a sincere question.

Comment: @abc: Take `a * b - c - d` as an example.  Precedence explains why it's interpreted as `(a * b) - c - d`.  Associativity explains why that is then interpreted as `((a * b) - c) - d` (instead of `(a * b) - (c - d)`).  The two are separate concepts.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I see, thanks. A better example would have been a - d - b * c. Agree?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth That's a good example, thanks. It's an unambiguous example -- it could not possibly be parsed any other way if you take `++` as a unary postfix operator -- but it is indeed not right-to-left, and when considering that example, I think I now agree that the GCC folks' choice of wording is not the best it could be.